# Mysql multiple insert query

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

On mysql data insertion, I have encountered following issue. Here email field cannot be null. While executing following queries (Query 1 & 2), we are expecting errors. But query 1 gives error and query 2 gives success.

Table Structre

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Query 1:

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `name`, `email`) VALUES (NULL, 'manu', NULL);
```

> Result:-#1048 - Column 'email' cannot be null

Query 2:

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `name`, `email`)
VALUES (NULL, 'manu', NULL),(NULL, 'Jose', NULL);
```

> Result:-2 rows inserted.

[image: Both query returns success.]

Is there any error in the query? Any thoughts will be appreciated.

Comment: This behavior is not reproducible on SQL Fiddle.  The second query generates the same error as the first.

Comment: What happens if you create a new table called "users2" with exactly the same structure, and try running the queries again? It'd be interesting to see what data ends up in the table after you run each query. I can't see why both queries wouldn't fail.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, We got this in Server version: 5.5.37-0ubuntu0.12.04.1-log (Ubuntu)

Comment: Isn't your SQL server operating in Strict mode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html)

> Inserting NULL into a column that has been declared NOT NULL. For
>   multiple-row INSERT statements or INSERT INTO ... SELECT statements,
>   the column is set to the implicit default value for the column data
>   type. This is 0 for numeric types, the empty string ('') for string
>   types, and the “zero” value for date and time types. INSERT INTO ...
>   SELECT statements are handled the same way as multiple-row inserts
>   because the server does not examine the result set from the SELECT to
>   see whether it returns a single row. (For a single-row INSERT, no
>   warning occurs when NULL is inserted into a NOT NULL column. Instead,
>   the statement fails with an error.)

Comment: In that case, what will be the default value for 'varchar' field?

Comment: For string types other than ENUM, the default value is the empty string. For ENUM, the default is the first enumeration value. - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/data-type-defaults.html